# Pass param to another component with react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass a parameter to a custom component called Cell with react. This is my code

```
<Cell cellTitle='test' style={styles.item}></Cell>

In Cell

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const cellTitle = props.cellTitle;
    console.log(cellTitle);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.title}>{cellTitle}</Text>. // I get the error here
    )
}
```

I get an error

```
Can't find variable cellTitle
```

Comment: try `this.props.cellTitle` instead of `cellTitle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you are assigning `cellTitle` to a const variable

```
const cellTitle = props.cellTitle;
```

This variable will no longer exist once your constructor finishes executing.

So either assign it to `state` or use `this.props.cellTitle` directly within your render method

Answer (score 1):

You have declared cellTitle as a const inside your constructor.
This is not known inside the render function.

You can just use props inside your render:

```
render() {
    return <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.cellTitle}</Text>;
}
```